# Underscore extend an object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I want to extend an object to add another attribute:

```
var days = [{day:'monday'},{day:'tuesday'}];
    _.extend(days,{day:'monday'},{name:'Peter'});

// DAYS NOT EXTENDED
console.log(days);
// I WANT TO HAVE AS RESULT
// [{day:'monday',name:'Peter'},{day:'tuesday'}]
```

The goal is to able to update or insert depending of the criteria, i want to find 'monday' and extend, 'tuesday' and extend and so on ...
if i find 'monday' again i want to remove the name attribute and replace it by the new criteria

============

## UPDATE

This is a solution from [T.J Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder), it update the object if i search with a new criteria but the same day :

```
var days = [{day:'monday'},{day:'tuesday'}];
var day = _.find(days, function(day) {
  return day.day == 'monday';
});

if (day) {
  _.extend(day,{day:'monday'},{name:'Peter'});
}

console.log(days);
```

This output (Here i search 'Monday' and insert Peter, i do the same for Ronald, and i search 'Monday' again and update the name with Sandy) :
The code update but insert also new day 'Monday' at the last of object

```
///// THE initial object
({
    'day':'Monday'
},{
    'day':'Tuesday'
})
///// search 'Monday' and add {name : 'Peter'}
({
    'name':'Peter',
    'day':'Monday'
},{
    'day':'Tuesday'
},{
    'day':'Monday'
})


//// search 'Monday' again and update with {name : 'Sandy'}
({
    'name':'Sandy',
    'day':'Monday'
},{
    'day':'Tuesday'
},{
    'day':'Monday'
},{
    'day':'Monday'
})
```

So my question is why it extends {day:'Monday'} for each update ?

Thank you

Comment: here you have an array of objects so if you need to change a specific object you need to find it using findWhere and replace it

Comment: Your expected format is not valid. You are missing `key` for `{name: 'Peter'}`

Comment: Hey, thanks for help, Ryad.iv could you give me an example please?

Comment: I edited my question, thanks Rajesh

Comment: @user44321 I added an answer

Comment: *I want to extend an object to add another attribute* Which object do you want to extend? What do you expect the `{day:'monday'}1` and `{name:'Peter'}` arguments to `_.extend` to do? Are those attributes you want to add to something? Or is the first a description of which object to add to, and the second what to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *does* add those properties to the array, they're just not being shown, and they're not being added where you want them to be because you aren't using `_.extend` in the way that would. You're extending the **array**; you want to extend the array's first entry. Here's what would do what you want, note the `[0]`:

```js
var days = [{day:'monday'},{day:'tuesday'}];
_.extend(days[0],{day:'monday'},{name:'Peter'});
// Note -----^^^

console.log(days);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Of course, that assumes you know the index of `day: 'monday'` is `0`. If you don't, you'll need to find the day first, perhaps using `_.find`:

```js
var days = [{day:'monday'},{day:'tuesday'}];
var day = _.find(days, function(day) {
  return day.day == 'monday';
});
if (day) {
  _.extend(day,{day:'monday'},{name:'Peter'});
}

console.log(days);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

---

In your edit to the question, you said that the code above keeps adding `{day: 'monday'}` to the array. It doesn't. Let's put it in a function and then repeatedly call that function:

```js
function extendDay(dayName, properties) {
  var day = _.find(days, function(day) {
    return day.day == dayName;
  });
  if (day) {
    _.extend(day, properties);
  }
}
var days = [{day:'monday'},{day:'tuesday'}];
extendDay('monday', {name: 'James'});
extendDay('tuesday', {name: 'Sandy'});
console.log("after first two updates:");
console.log(days);
extendDay('monday', {name: 'Peter'});
extendDay('tuesday', {name: 'Joseph'});
console.log("after second two updates:");
console.log(days);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

---

But as to why you weren't seeing anything with your code: When you `console.log` an array, many consoles make the assumption that you've used the array in the "normal" way and not added non-array-entry properties to it. Your code adds non-array-entry properties to the array.

```js
var days = [{day:'monday'},{day:'tuesday'}];
_.extend(days,{day:'monday'},{name:'Peter'});

console.log(days);
console.log(days.day);
console.log(days.name);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you a lot, i just wonder if i add the same day after, it will update ?, i mean remove the attribute name and add another

Comment: @user44321: It depends entirely on what you mean by "add the same day after." If you do it with `_.extend`, it won't *remove* `name` (`_.extend` just *adds* properties).

Comment: Thanks again, my aim is to update remove attribute by criteria above :
Find the day and add attribute, and so on ...
if i find again a day with another criteria, i want to override the name attribute

Comment: @user44321: Then the `_.find` and `_.extend` above is probably want you want. It will add or update things, but not remove previous things.

Comment: Thank you, it is working well, but with a little bug, each time i want to update, it insert new day at the last of object, i updated my post to illustrate it :)

Comment: @user44321: The code I gave you above doesn't do that. I've updated to demonstrate that it doesn't.

Comment: Hello, may be i did a mistake, i'll try again

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through to change the properties where the `day` is `Monday`

```js
var days = [{day:'monday'},{day:'tuesday'}];
    var dayName = "monday"
    var propExtend = _.extend({day:dayName},{name:'Peter'});

    for(var i = 0; i< days.length; i++){
    if(days[i].day == dayName){
    days[i] = propExtend;
    }
    }
    console.log(days)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Monasha, it will overwrite the attribute if i have a second dayName? i mean i want to update or insert

Answer (score 0):

```
var days = [{day:'monday'},{day:'tuesday'}];
var obj =_.where(days, {day: "Monday"});
_.extend(obj[0], {name:'Peter'});
for(int i=1; i<obj.length;i++){
   _.extend(obj[i], {newCriteria:'your value'});
}
```

this will change it since it has the same object reference.

although your question is not too specific about what to do with the occurrences

Comment: So obj is a new copy of days?

Comment: I edited the answer check it, obj is a copy with the same reference of the object containing day = monday so any change on it will be applied on the object in the array

Comment: This is probably the right answer assuming that's what the OP wants to do, but to me at least it's far from clear.